# Accessing JSON array's through object properites

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have the next JSON file:

```
{
  "shows": [
             {
               "name": "House of cards",
               "rating": 8
             },
             {
               "name": "Breaking bad",
               "rating": 10
             }
  ]
}
```

I want to access the rating of a show, by it's name. Something like this:

```
var rating = data.shows["House of cards"].rating;
```

Is this possible? Or something similar? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `var rating = rating.shows[0].rating;`

Comment: @batman191 Double-check my answer, I believe it will make things simpler in the code where you may be accessing shows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have such hash-style access just by deserializing that JSON sample.

Maybe you might be able to re-formulate how the data is serialized into JSON and use object literals even for shows:

```
{
    "shows": {
         "House of cards": {
             "rating": 8
         }
     }
}
```

And you can still obtain an array of show keys using `Object.keys(...)`:

```
Object.keys(x.shows);
```

Or you can even change the structure once you deserialize that JSON:

```
var x = { shows: {} };

for(var index in some.shows) {
   x.shows[some.shows[index].name] = { rating: some.shows[index].rating };
}

// Accessing a show
var rating = x.shows["House of cards"].rating;
```

I suggest you that it should be better to do this *conversion* and gain the benefit of accessing your shows using plain JavaScript, rather than having to iterate the whole show array to find one.

When you use object literals, you're accessing properties like a dictionary/hash table, which makes no use of any search function behind the scenes.

### Update

OP has concerns about how to iterate shows once it's an associative array/object instead of regular array:

```
Object.keys(shows).forEach(function(showTitle) {
    // Do stuff here for each iteration
});
```

Or...

```
for(var showTitle in shows) {
    // Do stuff here for each iteration
}
```

### Update 2

Here's a working sample on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dst4U/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rating = {
  "shows": [
             {
               "name": "House of cards",
               "rating": 8
             },
             {
               "name": "Breaking bad",
               "rating": 10
             }
  ]
};
rating.shows.forEach(findsearchkey);

function findsearchkey(element, index, array) {
  if( element.name == 'House of cards' ) {
    console.log( array[index].rating );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/yqDg7/)

```
var data = {"shows": [{"name": "House of cards","rating": 8},{"name": "Breaking bad","rating": 10}]};
var shows = data.shows;
var showOfRatingToBeFound = "House of cards";
for(var a in shows){
    if(shows[a].name == showOfRatingToBeFound){
       alert("Rating Of "+ showOfRatingToBeFound+ " is " +shows[a].rating);
    }
}
```